Can't connect SPD-SAY and Festival
I'm using Puppy Linux:
Linux PuppyPC 4.9.163-lxpup-32-pae #1 SMP Thu Mar 14 15:41:19 GMT 2019 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

I'm trying to use spd-say tool with festival. The problem is I can use festival by itself using this command:
echo "Hello world" | festival --tts

but not the spd-say
spd-say "Hello world"

Whatever I do I get the same error:
Failed to connect to Speech Dispatcher:
Error: Can't connect to unix socket /root/.cache/speech-dispatcher/speechd.sock: No such file or directory. Autospawn: Autospawn failed. Speech Dispatcher refused to start with error code, stating this as a reason:

I don't have this file /root/.cache/speech-dispatcher/speechd.sock
I can run festival server:
# festival --server
server    Sun Jul 21 15:18:09 2024 : Festival server started on port 1314

and when I try to use sdp-say I got this messages on server:
client(1) Sun Jul 21 15:19:32 2024 : accepted from localhost
client(1) Sun Jul 21 15:19:33 2024 : disconnected

As you can see it disconnects immediately. A while before there also was an error SIOD: unknown voice cmu_us_aew_cg but after reading this question I solved the issue
Additional info:
I installed these packages:

/etc/speech-dispatcher/speechd.conf:
LogLevel  5
LogDir  "/var/log/speech-dispatcher/"
DefaultVolume 100
AddModule "festival"     "sd_festival"  "festival.conf"
DefaultModule festival
Include "clients/*.conf"

/usr/share/speech-dispatcher/conf/speechd.conf:
LogLevel  3
LogDir  "stdout"
DefaultVolume 100
AddModule "festival"     "sd_festival"  "festival.conf"
DefaultModule festival
Include "clients/*.conf"

/usr/share/festival/voices/us/cmu_us_aew_cg/festvox/cmu_us_aew_cg.scm (at the end):
(proclaim_voice
 'cmu_us_aew_cg
 '((language english)
   (gender male)
   (dialect american)
   (description
    "This voice provides an American English male voice using a
     residual excited LPC diphone synthesis method.  It uses
     the CMU Lexicon pronunciations.  Prosodic phrasing is provided
     by a statistically trained model using part of speech and local
     distribution of breaks.  Intonation is provided by a CART tree
     predicting ToBI accents and an F0 contour generated from a model
     trained from natural speech.  The duration model is also trained
     from data using a CART tree.")))

(provide 'cmu_us_aew_cg)

/etc/festival.scm (at the end):
(set! voice_default 'voice_cmu_us_aew_cg)

Logs:
/var/log/speech-dispatcher/speech-dispatcher.log:
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 56876] speechd:   Speech Dispatcher Logging to file /var/log/speech-dispatcher//speech-dispatcher.log
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 57338] speechd:     Module name=festival being inserted into requested_modules list
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 83160] speechd:    Reading configuration for pattern emacs:*
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 83377] speechd:  Configuration has been read from "/etc/speech-dispatcher/speechd.conf"
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 121762] speechd:     Module name=espeak being inserted into detected_modules list
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 121864] speechd:     Module name=pico being inserted into detected_modules list
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 121928] speechd:     Module name=dummy being inserted into detected_modules list
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 121991] speechd:     Module name=festival being inserted into detected_modules list
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 122053] speechd:     Module name=cicero being inserted into detected_modules list
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 122116] speechd:     Module name=generic being inserted into detected_modules list
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 122179] speechd:     Module name=flite being inserted into detected_modules list
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 122242] speechd:     Module name=espeak-ng being inserted into detected_modules list
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 122302] speechd:     Module name=espeak being inserted into requested_modules list
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 122346] speechd:     Module name=pico being inserted into requested_modules list
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 122388] speechd:     Module name=dummy being inserted into requested_modules list
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 122429] speechd: Load request for module festival with command sd_festival and configuration file festival.conf was previously received; ignoring the second one.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 122539] speechd:     Module name=cicero being inserted into requested_modules list
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 122591] speechd:     Module name=generic being inserted into requested_modules list
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 122634] speechd:     Module name=flite being inserted into requested_modules list
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 122676] speechd:     Module name=espeak-ng being inserted into requested_modules list
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 122882] speechd:  Initializing output module festival with binary /usr/lib/speech-dispatcher-modules/sd_festival and configuration /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/festival.conf
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 122941] speechd:   Output module is logging to file /var/log/speech-dispatcher//festival.log
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 123823] speechd:  Module festival loaded.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 123948] speechd:    Trying to initialize festival.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 124017] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |INIT
| (0)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 492539] speechd:     Reply from output module: 480 399-Communicating with Festival through a socket. Can't connect to Festival server. Check your configuration in etc/speechd-modules/festival.conf for the specified host and port and check if Festival is really running there, e.g. with telnet. Please see documentation for more info.

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 492678] speechd:     Reply from output module: 480 399 ERR CANT INIT MODULE

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 492746] speechd: ERROR: Module festival failed to initialize. Reason: 
---------------
Communicating with Festival through a socket. Can't connect to Festival server. Check your configuration in etc/speechd-modules/festival.conf for the specified host and port and check if Festival is really running there, e.g. with telnet. Please see documentation for more info.
---------------

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 493050] speechd:  Initializing output module espeak with binary /usr/lib/speech-dispatcher-modules/sd_espeak and configuration /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/espeak.conf
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 493121] speechd:   Output module is logging to file /var/log/speech-dispatcher//espeak.log
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 493857] speechd:  Module espeak loaded.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 494205] speechd:    Trying to initialize espeak.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:38 2024 : 494324] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |INIT
| (0)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:39 2024 : 396219] speechd:     Reply from output module: 120 299-Espeak: Initialized successfully.

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:39 2024 : 396329] speechd:     Reply from output module: 120 299 OK LOADED SUCCESSFULLY

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:39 2024 : 396406] speechd:  Module espeak started successfully with message: 
---------------
Espeak: Initialized successfully.
---------------

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:39 2024 : 396519] speechd:    Module set parameters.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:39 2024 : 396624] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |AUDIO
| (1)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:39 2024 : 396722] speechd:     Got 32 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:39 2024 : 396767] speechd:     Reply from output module: |207 OK RECEIVING AUDIO SETTINGS
|
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:39 2024 : 396827] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |audio_output_method=pulse
audio_oss_device=/dev/dsp
audio_alsa_device=default
audio_nas_server=tcp/localhost:5450
audio_pulse_server=default
audio_pulse_min_length=100
| (0)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:39 2024 : 396891] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |.
| (1)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:39 2024 : 514202] speechd:     Got 70 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:39 2024 : 514318] speechd:     Got 18 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:39 2024 : 514363] speechd:     Reply from output module: |300-Opening sound device failed. Reason: Couldn't open pulse plugin. 
300 UNKNOWN ERROR
|
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:39 2024 : 514404] speechd:  Error: Module reported error in request from speechd (code 3xx): 300-Opening sound device failed. Reason: Couldn't open pulse plugin. 
300 UNKNOWN ERROR
.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:39 2024 : 514483] speechd: ERROR: Can't initialize audio in output module, see reason above.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:39 2024 : 514808] speechd:  Initializing output module pico with binary /usr/lib/speech-dispatcher-modules/sd_pico and configuration /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/pico.conf
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:39 2024 : 514873] speechd:   Output module is logging to file /var/log/speech-dispatcher//pico.log
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:39 2024 : 515672] speechd:  Module pico loaded.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:39 2024 : 515846] speechd:    Trying to initialize pico.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:39 2024 : 515927] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |INIT
| (0)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 139013] speechd:     Reply from output module: 120 299-pico: Initialized successfully.

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 139141] speechd:     Reply from output module: 120 299 OK LOADED SUCCESSFULLY

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 139223] speechd:  Module pico started successfully with message: 
---------------
pico: Initialized successfully.
---------------

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 139280] speechd:    Module set parameters.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 139373] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |AUDIO
| (1)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 139644] speechd:     Got 32 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 139742] speechd:     Reply from output module: |207 OK RECEIVING AUDIO SETTINGS
|
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 140050] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |audio_output_method=pulse
audio_oss_device=/dev/dsp
audio_alsa_device=default
audio_nas_server=tcp/localhost:5450
audio_pulse_server=default
audio_pulse_min_length=100
| (0)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 140153] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |.
| (1)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 151542] speechd:     Got 70 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 151744] speechd:     Got 18 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 151803] speechd:     Reply from output module: |300-Opening sound device failed. Reason: Couldn't open pulse plugin. 
300 UNKNOWN ERROR
|
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 151847] speechd:  Error: Module reported error in request from speechd (code 3xx): 300-Opening sound device failed. Reason: Couldn't open pulse plugin. 
300 UNKNOWN ERROR
.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 151920] speechd: ERROR: Can't initialize audio in output module, see reason above.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 152641] speechd:  Initializing output module dummy with binary /usr/lib/speech-dispatcher-modules/sd_dummy and configuration /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/dummy.conf
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 152736] speechd:   Output module is logging to file /var/log/speech-dispatcher//dummy.log
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 153516] speechd:  Module dummy loaded.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 153674] speechd:    Trying to initialize dummy.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 153795] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |INIT
| (0)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 197641] speechd:     Reply from output module: 120 299-Everything ok so far.

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 197740] speechd:     Reply from output module: 120 299 OK LOADED SUCCESSFULLY

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 197796] speechd:  Module dummy started successfully with message: 
---------------
Everything ok so far.
---------------

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 197841] speechd:    Module set parameters.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 197925] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |AUDIO
| (1)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 198023] speechd:     Got 32 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 198067] speechd:     Reply from output module: |207 OK RECEIVING AUDIO SETTINGS
|
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 198128] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |audio_output_method=pulse
audio_oss_device=/dev/dsp
audio_alsa_device=default
audio_nas_server=tcp/localhost:5450
audio_pulse_server=default
audio_pulse_min_length=100
| (0)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 198194] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |.
| (1)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 208561] speechd:     Got 70 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 208683] speechd:     Got 18 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 208729] speechd:     Reply from output module: |300-Opening sound device failed. Reason: Couldn't open pulse plugin. 
300 UNKNOWN ERROR
|
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 208771] speechd:  Error: Module reported error in request from speechd (code 3xx): 300-Opening sound device failed. Reason: Couldn't open pulse plugin. 
300 UNKNOWN ERROR
.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 208816] speechd: ERROR: Can't initialize audio in output module, see reason above.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 209108] speechd:  Initializing output module cicero with binary /usr/lib/speech-dispatcher-modules/sd_cicero and configuration /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/cicero.conf
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 209171] speechd:   Output module is logging to file /var/log/speech-dispatcher//cicero.log
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 209845] speechd:  Module cicero loaded.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 209977] speechd:    Trying to initialize cicero.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 210075] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |INIT
| (0)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 270484] speechd:     Reply from output module: 120 299-Cicero initialized successfully.

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 270785] speechd:     Reply from output module: 120 299 OK LOADED SUCCESSFULLY

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 270902] speechd:  Module cicero started successfully with message: 
---------------
Cicero initialized successfully.
---------------

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 270963] speechd:    Module set parameters.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 271056] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |AUDIO
| (1)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 271280] speechd:     Got 32 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 271340] speechd:     Reply from output module: |207 OK RECEIVING AUDIO SETTINGS
|
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 271400] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |audio_output_method=pulse
audio_oss_device=/dev/dsp
audio_alsa_device=default
audio_nas_server=tcp/localhost:5450
audio_pulse_server=default
audio_pulse_min_length=100
| (0)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 271498] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |.
| (1)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 287512] speechd:     Got 70 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 287714] speechd:     Got 18 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 287777] speechd:     Reply from output module: |300-Opening sound device failed. Reason: Couldn't open pulse plugin. 
300 UNKNOWN ERROR
|
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 287831] speechd:  Error: Module reported error in request from speechd (code 3xx): 300-Opening sound device failed. Reason: Couldn't open pulse plugin. 
300 UNKNOWN ERROR
.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 287891] speechd: ERROR: Can't initialize audio in output module, see reason above.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 288290] speechd:  Initializing output module generic with binary /usr/lib/speech-dispatcher-modules/sd_generic and configuration /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/generic.conf
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 288398] speechd:   Output module is logging to file /var/log/speech-dispatcher//generic.log
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 290207] speechd:  Module generic loaded.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 290354] speechd:    Trying to initialize generic.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 290514] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |INIT
| (0)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 319844] speechd:     Reply from output module: 120 299-Everything ok so far.

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 319937] speechd:     Reply from output module: 120 299 OK LOADED SUCCESSFULLY

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 319998] speechd:  Module generic started successfully with message: 
---------------
Everything ok so far.
---------------

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 320044] speechd:    Module set parameters.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 320114] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |AUDIO
| (1)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 320263] speechd:     Got 32 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 320311] speechd:     Reply from output module: |207 OK RECEIVING AUDIO SETTINGS
|
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 320372] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |audio_output_method=pulse
audio_oss_device=/dev/dsp
audio_alsa_device=default
audio_nas_server=tcp/localhost:5450
audio_pulse_server=default
audio_pulse_min_length=100
| (0)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 320518] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |.
| (1)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 329945] speechd:     Got 70 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 330052] speechd:     Got 18 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 330098] speechd:     Reply from output module: |300-Opening sound device failed. Reason: Couldn't open pulse plugin. 
300 UNKNOWN ERROR
|
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 330138] speechd:  Error: Module reported error in request from speechd (code 3xx): 300-Opening sound device failed. Reason: Couldn't open pulse plugin. 
300 UNKNOWN ERROR
.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 330183] speechd: ERROR: Can't initialize audio in output module, see reason above.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 330477] speechd:  Initializing output module flite with binary /usr/lib/speech-dispatcher-modules/sd_flite and configuration /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/flite.conf
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 330552] speechd:   Output module is logging to file /var/log/speech-dispatcher//flite.log
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 331177] speechd:  Module flite loaded.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 331299] speechd:    Trying to initialize flite.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 331372] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |INIT
| (0)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 522342] speechd:     Reply from output module: 120 299-Flite initialized successfully.

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 522546] speechd:     Reply from output module: 120 299 OK LOADED SUCCESSFULLY

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 522652] speechd:  Module flite started successfully with message: 
---------------
Flite initialized successfully.
---------------

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 522715] speechd:    Module set parameters.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 522819] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |AUDIO
| (1)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 523045] speechd:     Got 32 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 523175] speechd:     Reply from output module: |207 OK RECEIVING AUDIO SETTINGS
|
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 523251] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |audio_output_method=pulse
audio_oss_device=/dev/dsp
audio_alsa_device=default
audio_nas_server=tcp/localhost:5450
audio_pulse_server=default
audio_pulse_min_length=100
| (0)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 523316] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |.
| (1)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 556700] speechd:     Got 70 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 556853] speechd:     Got 18 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 556911] speechd:     Reply from output module: |300-Opening sound device failed. Reason: Couldn't open pulse plugin. 
300 UNKNOWN ERROR
|
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 556964] speechd:  Error: Module reported error in request from speechd (code 3xx): 300-Opening sound device failed. Reason: Couldn't open pulse plugin. 
300 UNKNOWN ERROR
.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 557021] speechd: ERROR: Can't initialize audio in output module, see reason above.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 557328] speechd:  Initializing output module espeak-ng with binary /usr/lib/speech-dispatcher-modules/sd_espeak-ng and configuration /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/espeak-ng.conf
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 557403] speechd:   Output module is logging to file /var/log/speech-dispatcher//espeak-ng.log
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 558358] speechd:  Module espeak-ng loaded.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 558556] speechd:    Trying to initialize espeak-ng.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:40 2024 : 558698] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |INIT
| (0)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:41 2024 : 280245] speechd:     Reply from output module: 120 299-Espeak-ng: Initialized successfully.

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:41 2024 : 280359] speechd:     Reply from output module: 120 299 OK LOADED SUCCESSFULLY

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:41 2024 : 280510] speechd:  Module espeak-ng started successfully with message: 
---------------
Espeak-ng: Initialized successfully.
---------------

[Sun Jul 21 15:48:41 2024 : 280587] speechd:    Module set parameters.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:41 2024 : 280681] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |AUDIO
| (1)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:41 2024 : 280779] speechd:     Got 32 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:41 2024 : 280823] speechd:     Reply from output module: |207 OK RECEIVING AUDIO SETTINGS
|
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:41 2024 : 280883] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |audio_output_method=pulse
audio_oss_device=/dev/dsp
audio_alsa_device=default
audio_nas_server=tcp/localhost:5450
audio_pulse_server=default
audio_pulse_min_length=100
| (0)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:41 2024 : 280948] speechd:     Command sent to output module: |.
| (1)
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:41 2024 : 284369] speechd:     Got 70 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:41 2024 : 284531] speechd:     Got 18 bytes from output module over socket
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:41 2024 : 284584] speechd:     Reply from output module: |300-Opening sound device failed. Reason: Couldn't open pulse plugin. 
300 UNKNOWN ERROR
|
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:41 2024 : 284625] speechd:  Error: Module reported error in request from speechd (code 3xx): 300-Opening sound device failed. Reason: Couldn't open pulse plugin. 
300 UNKNOWN ERROR
.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:41 2024 : 284670] speechd: ERROR: Can't initialize audio in output module, see reason above.
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:41 2024 : 284808] speechd:   Speech Dispatcher Logging to file /var/log/speech-dispatcher//speech-dispatcher.log
[Sun Jul 21 15:48:41 2024 : 284890] speechd: Error [speechd.c:649]:No speech output modules were loaded - aborting...

If you need more info please ask me in comments and I will provide as more information as I can

The problem was solved by changing file /etc/speech-dispatcher/speechd.conf
I had to uncomment and change AudioOutputMethod option to alsa
